# milliseconds are missing in dataset after getting from database c#

Tags: c#

hey guys when i get data from database my timeStamp is as follow:

```
timeStamp='2021-02-04 13:01:46.96'
```

my database call:

```
       NpgsqlDataAdapter adapt = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * from logs.func_event_log(
                             '" + id + @"',
                             '" + myDateFrom + @" 00:00:00' , '" + myDateTo + @" 23:59:59.999' 
                             ,'FULLEVENTLOG' 
                        )
                         res (m_time_stamp timestamp without time zone, m_event_log_description text, 
                         m_user_description varchar,  m_event_type_description varchar,
                         m_wind_speed real, m_rpm real , m_power real, 
                          m_event_type_id int,  m_event_number varchar)  ", cn);
```

when I fill the dataset

```
      var data = (from t in ds.AsEnumerable()
                            select new EventEntryForAllTurbines
                            {
                                Timestamp = (DateTime)t["m_time_stamp"],
                                Description = (string)t["m_event_log_description"],
                                WindSpeed = (float)t["m_wind_speed"],
                            }).OrderBy(s=>s.Timestamp);
```

in my dataset, I see my milliseconds are removed in TimeStamp, my timestamp is DateTime type, how can I keep my milliseconds?

here is the screenshot of my breakpoint and values its shown

[image: Mili]

here is the screenshot of my DB

[image: db]

I have a class to convert time to send to view

```
      result.Add("DateTime", eventEntry.Timestamp.ToString
  (Culture.GetCulture().DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern) 
  + " " + eventEntry.Timestamp.ToString(Culture.GetCulture()
     .DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern));
```

Comment: could you please provide a more reproducible example of your problem? also: what database _exactly_? and what's the _exact_ type and value of `t["m_time_stamp"]`?

Comment: There isn't any information in the code that you've shared that shows what the problem is. You need to share a larger context scope, perhaps more code or something reproducible such as github.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann type is an object from the database as you can see in my edited question

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***. and i have a strong gut feeling that your problem is a side symptom of using concatenation, as well.

Comment: How did you determine the milliseconds were lost?

Comment: @mjwills i put a breakpoint and see the value

Comment: At the breakpoint, please share the `Ticks` value of the datetime.

Comment: Please share the source code of `func_event_log`.

Comment: [DateTimeFormatInfo.LongTimePattern Property (System.Globalization) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longtimepattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please make absolutely sure the milliseconds are truly missing. Look what happens when I point to a datetime variable:

[image]
The tooltip looks like no milliseconds, but the locals window clearly shows that they're there, as does TimeOfDay etc

Comment: thanks for the comments please see my edited question, I have attached the screenshot

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the query run in your db query tool for this exact row that is showing in your locals window?

Comment: i have added  the screenshot of the query

Comment: Honestly, I can't see any problem. Your query shows the time as `3:43.4` and the locals window shows TimeOfDay as `3:43.4000000` so these two are the same and nothing appears to be missing. 400 is in the milliseconds, which are out of 1000, and 400 / 1000 is 0.4 - everything matches up so far

Comment: sorry, I missed writing this part I have a class that converts my time to pass to view i have added to my question(bottom) can you see that? could be the part that eliminates my milliseconds? because i don't see it in my grid on the view

Comment: @mortezasol You are adding the DateTime as string value. What *is* the value  of that string?